# ChartJs: Different color fill between points makes lines straight...need curves (lineTension)

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I am building a line chart with different background colors between data points. When I break my dataset into the following the lineTension is lost and shows straight lines. How can I make the curves?

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [73, 59, null, null],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(233, 104, 92, 0.3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(233, 104, 92, 0.3)",
        pointRadius: 0,
        lineTension: 0.4,

    }, {
        data: [null, 59, 70, null],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(92, 193, 77, 0.3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(92, 193, 77, 0.3)",
        pointRadius: 0,
        lineTension: 0.4
    }, {
        data: [null, null, 70, 55],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(233, 104, 92, 0.3)",
        borderColor: "rgba(233, 104, 92, 0.3)",
        pointRadius: 0,
        lineTension: 0.4
    }
    ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var options = {
   showTooltips: false,
}

var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Linetension is actually working, but you're only show 2 datapoints for each dataset. You need 3 to show a curve.

Also, it seems like you're using an old version of ChartJs, the latest version uses the following syntax:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, { type: "line", data: data,options: options });
```